# INSERT в Базу данных

Tags: php, html, mysql

Уже перепроверил с админ. части INSERT отрабатывает, проблема во фронте:

```
case 'booking':
    $a = $_POST["hotelid"]." ".$_POST["roomid"]." ".$_POST["dtarrive"]." ".$_POST["dtdepart"]." ".$_POST["price"]." ".$_POST["email"];
    echo $a;
    bookingCreate($_POST["hotelid"],$_POST["roomid"],$_POST["dtarrive"],$_POST["dtdepart"],$_POST["price"],$_POST["email"]);
```

Проверяю `echo` приходит, а в common не отрабатывается, подскажите что упускаю???

```
function bookingCreate($hotelid, $roomid, $dtarrive, $dtdepart, $price, $email) {
    $cn = dbConnect();
    $timearrive = strtotime($dtarrive);
    $timedepart = strtotime($dtdepart);
    $newformatarrive = date('Y-m-d',$timearrive);
    $newformatdepart = date('Y-m-d',$timedepart);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbooking(hotelid, roomid, dtarrive, dtdepart, userid, bookingcode, price, status, email) VALUES (".$hotelid.",".$roomid.",'".$newformatarrive."', '".$newformatdepart."','0', UUID(), ".$price.", '1', '".$email."')");
    mysql_close($cn);
}
```

Comment: `$sql = "INSERT INTO tbooking(hotelid, roomid, dtarrive, dtdepart, userid, bookingcode, price, status, email) VALUES (".$hotelid.",".$roomid.",'".$newformatarrive."', '".$newformatdepart."','0', UUID(), ".$price.", '1', '".$email."')"` напечатайте это , и проверьте phpmyadmin. `echo $sql; die();`

Comment: кто такой `common`? При ошибках обычно есть логи.... вы смотрели в них?

Comment: require_once('smarty/Smarty.class.php');
require_once("./modules/common.php");
Ошибок нет, со страницы на index.php приходит POST,GET переменные, а после данные отправляются в Common.php но Insert не делается, в админском index insert работает

Comment: `function bookingInsert($hotelid, $roomid, $dtarrive, $dtdepart, $userid, $price, $status, $email){
$cn = dbConnect();
$timearrive = strtotime($dtarrive);
$timedepart = strtotime($dtdepart);
$newformatarrive = date('Y-m-d',$timearrive);
$newformatdepart = date('Y-m-d',$timedepart);
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbooking(hotelid, roomid, dtarrive, dtdepart, userid, bookingcode, price, status, email) VALUES (".$hotelid.",".$roomid.",'".$newformatarrive."', '".$newformatdepart."',".$userid.", UUID(), ".$price.",".$status.",'".$email."')");
 mysql_close($cn);`
Это админский, он работает

Comment: надеюсь вы отдаете себе отчет, что будет, если в качестве `email` пользователь вдруг напишет `xxx'); delete from tbooking; #`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bookingCreate($_POST["hotelid"], 
              $_POST["roomid"], 
              $_POST["dtarrive"], 
              $_POST["dtdepart"], 
              $_POST["price"], 
              $_POST["email"]
         );
```

Все правильно, проблема заключается в поле `price`, пока неясно почему, когда убираешь атрибут `disabled` с поля `price`, все садится в базу.

Comment: если у вас поле `disabled` то оно не отправляется в `POST`, поэтому значение будет `null`. Тут надо удостовериться, что соответствующее поле БД может принимать значение `NULL`. либо смотреть логику метода `bookingCreate()`

Comment: пардоньте, `bookingPrice` приведен. Когда у вас там `$price == null` то в запросе получается две запятых подряд, что дает синтаксическую ошибку. В админской версии небось пустой price никогда не приходит, поэтому все норм.

Comment: @teran price был сделан disabled отображаемый и hidden для передачи. Вы говорили : 
надеюсь вы отдаете себе отчет, что будет, если в качестве email пользователь вдруг напишет xxx'); delete from tbooking; #
Могли бы объяснить подробнее? Поле имеет тип email